# Jquery Drag and drop using keyboard

Tags: jquery, html

Is there any way in switch we can implement jquery drag and drop using keyboard events rather than mouse

```
switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
        if($('.slick-track').has('.selecteds'))
        {
            var getID = $('.selecteds').attr('id'); 
            var name = '#'+getID
            var myDraggable = $(name).draggable();
            var widget = myDraggable.data('ui-draggable');
        }
    // $('.selecteds').stop().animate({
    // left: '-=10'
    // }); //left arrow key
    break;
```

Comment: Do you want `mouse` **+** `keyboard`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [keypress()](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)?

```
$( ".selecteds" ).keypress(function( event ) {
   if ( event.which == 37 ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this)animate({
          left: '-=10'
        }); 
    }       
 })
```

Something like that if I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly.